# Select from table A depending on some field in table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

```
TableA (TableAId int PK, Name varchar) 
TableB (OtherId, TableAId FK, TimeBegin timestamp ,TimeEnd timestamp)
```

I want to select from TableA Name(s), which have TimeEnd = NULL in TableB.

Tried something like this:

```
SELECT     TableAId, Name
FROM       TableA
WHERE      
(
TableAId NOT IN 
                (
                 SELECT TableAId FROM TableB WHERE TimeEnd is null
                )
);
```

It works fine, when i have some records that have null TimeEnd and some with not null TimeEnd, but it doesnt work when i have no records with no TimeEnd set.

How to fix it?

Comment: timestamp is not actually a time related datatype. Did you mean DATETIME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question there are two possible answers:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableB') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableA') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA
  (
    TableAId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
  ); 
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB
  (
    OtherId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TableAId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TableA ( TableAId ),
    TimeBegin DATETIME,
    TimeEnd DATETIME
  );


INSERT  INTO dbo.TableA
        ( TableAId, Name )
VALUES  ( 1, 'aaa' ),
        ( 2, 'bbb' ),
        ( 3, 'ccc' ),
        ( 4, 'ddd' );

INSERT  INTO dbo.TableB
        ( OtherId, TableAId, TimeBegin, TimeEnd )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, GETDATE(), NULL ),
        ( 2, 2, GETDATE(), GETDATE() ),
        ( 3, 2, GETDATE(), NULL ),
        ( 4, 3, GETDATE(), GETDATE() );


SELECT  A.*
FROM    dbo.TableA A
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   dbo.TableB B
                 WHERE  A.TableAId = B.TableAId
                        AND B.TimeEnd IS NULL );

SELECT  A.*
FROM    dbo.TableA A
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   dbo.TableB B
                 WHERE  A.TableAId = B.TableAId
                        AND B.TimeEnd IS NULL )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM   dbo.TableB B
                         WHERE  A.TableAId = B.TableAId
                                AND B.TimeEnd IS NOT NULL );
```

The first select returns all records from TableA for which AT LEAST ONE matching record in TableB exists with TimeEnd IS NULL.

The second select returns records from TableA for which ALL matching records in TableB fullfil TimeEnd IS NULL.

The second select can be rewritten as

```
SELECT  A.*
FROM    dbo.TableA A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  TableAId,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN TimeEnd IS NULL THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END) AllAreNull
            FROM    dbo.TableB
            GROUP BY TableAId
          ) AS B
        ON A.TableAId = B.TableAId
WHERE   B.AllAreNull = 1;
```

This is a little less easy to understand but should execute significantly faster in most cases. But you should run your own performance tests to make sure.

If each record in TableA has at most one record in TableB you can go with the first select statement.

Finally, your code does not match the describing text. If you are actually looking for records that have the endtime valued you need to switch out IS NULL with IS NOT NULL and vice versa in all above select statements.

Comment: I cant believe it must be so complicated. I was thinking on some subselect too (select with left join, then filter it), but your last query based on subselect with groping is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select * from TableA a
Left Join TableB b ON a.TableAId = b.TableAId 
WHERE b.TimeEnd IS NULL
```

For Not Null

```
Select * from TableA a
Left Join TableB b ON a.TableAId = b.TableAId 
WHERE b.TimeEnd IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: this might cause records to be duplicated if there is more then one child in table b for a specific row in table a

Comment: I need records that have no nulls there.

Comment: Try inner joins instead of left joins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to join the 2 tables first as the following example demonstrates:

```
SELECT     TableA.TableAId, TableA.Name
FROM       TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.TableAId = TableB.TableAId
WHERE      
(
TableA.TableAId NOT IN 
                (
                 SELECT TableAId FROM TableB WHERE TimeEnd is null
                )
);
```

Comment: This also might cause duplication of records.

Comment: Inner join will not select Id's which not exist in TableB.